# Magento : Checkout as guest using SMS OTP

Tags: php, magento

I want my customers of Magento store to be able to checkout as guest, but to confirm the details I need to generate OTP on entered mobile number and verify it. 
I have SMS API but dont know how to integrate the SMS API into Magento especially in the checkout as guest option.
Thanks

Comment: Im looking for same. Did you get any solution?

Comment: Checkout this https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html